# How many iterations are required for iterative-lengthening search when step costs are drawing from a continuos range [0, 1]?

Tags: search

I just started studying the book AI A modern Approach and I am lost on the following question. Could someone explain please or provide reference paper to understand.
Consider the step costs drawn from the continuous range [0,1] with a minimum positive cost e. How many iterations are required in the worst case?

I know it has already been answered but it does not explain the answer(
[How many iterations are required for iterative-lengthening search when step costs are drawing from a continuos range [ϵ, 1]?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/how-many-iterations-are-required-for-iterative-lengthening-search-when-step-cost))